# Axios post request from react results in empty or weird body

Tags: axios

Working on my first MERN stack application. I'm trying to make an axios post request from my React client (port **3000**) to my MongoDB API (port **3001**). My post request code is:

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          axios({
            method: "post",
            url:
              "http://localhost:3000/api/update/documentID",
            data: { newNumber: 12345 },
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
          });
        }}
      >
        Click to run axios post request
</button>
```

This results in a body showing up on my port 3001 server as:

```
body: { '{"newNumber":12345}': '' }
```

I have my React proxy server set up and body-parser installed on my port 3001 server. I'm able to make the exact request I want using Postman. I can also get exactly what I want by replacing my Button in React with a Form, but obviously having to submit a form to make a post request isn't ideal.

(Also, if I try to use axios.post(etc) instead of `axios({ method: post, etc.)`, I end up with an entirely empty body.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're using Postman, ensure the request has properly set the `Content-Type: application/json` and using the `raw` format in the Body tab and not the `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question, changed

```
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
```

to

```
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
```

and it worked.